# Bayes estimator (Inference)

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian

An urn contain 5 balls, $ \theta $ white and $ 5 - \theta $ green. The experiment consists in grab 2 balls from the urn and register the pair $(x_1, x_2)$, where $x_i = 1$ if we observe a white ball and $x_i = 0$ otherwise. What is the bayes estimator $ \theta^* $ for $ \theta$ considering the squared loss function? (i.e   $l(\theta,\theta^*) = (\theta - \theta^*)^2 $)

I can't figure out which posterior distribution I should use or even if I need to use one. I calculated my loss function considering all the possible values for $ \theta $ and $ \theta^* $ but I can't calculate the risk function without the posterior function.
Can someone help me with it??

I can't find out what to do with the ordered pair, I just calculated the probability of each pair

Comment: Don't you need a prior?

Comment: Yes, I do. I was thinking to give equal probability for each value of $ \theta $ using $f(\theta) = 1/6 $ for $\theta = 0,...,6 $ or not consider only integer values and put an uniform distribution. But I don't have any idea how to finish this problem.

Comment: Or I can find a posterior using bayes theorem but I'm stuck in this idea too.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture8.pdf Look at Theorem 7. With a squared loss function the Bayes estimator is the mean of the posterior distribution. So if you use your uniform prior and calculate the posterior you just need to find the mean of it.

Comment: Thank you hejseb, but I am having troubles to "see" the problem. When I use an uniform distribution for my prior, $ \theta$ is usually a proportion or a probability for something. But, in this case, my $\theta$ is a number between 0 and 5. How can a uniform model this? And using an uniform distribution, what distribution for $X_i$ should I use to get a known distribution for my posterior? Maybe a bernoulli with parameter $ \theta/5$ ?

Comment: The discrete uniform is $1/n$, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete). The distribution of $X$ should be hypergeometric. Using Wikipedia's notation, you have $K=\theta$, $N=5$ and $n=2$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: Not sure about conjugacy though.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the continuous uniform. As I said, I was thinking to give equiprobable probability for all the values of theta. There is, $ f(\theta) = 1/6 for \theta = 0, ..., 5 $  For X, why use hypergeometric? I mean, I understand why you are proposing it, but I was thinking in $ X_1, X_2$ random variables such that $ X_i = 1$ if the ith ball is white and 0 otherwise. Is this case, we could do $X_i \to ber(\theta/5) $ but in this case, we must consider replacement.

Comment: The probability for the first one is $\theta/5$, yes, but it isn't for the second one. The probability is either $\frac{\theta-1}{4}$ or $\frac{\theta}{4}$. The draws are not independent.

Comment: Using the formulas for the hypergeometric distribution is probably overkill, though. Just calculate by hand the probabilities for (green,green), (green,white), etc. given $\theta$.

Comment: it was my first plan, oscar. I already calculated in function of theta. So we are back to my first problem: how to find the posterior? I tried it using bayes theorem but , in this case, I will need to calculate for each pair (x1, x2), right?

Comment: Even calculating my prior for each possible pair (x1, x2) (because I dont have a general formula for P(x1,x2), I dont know how to calculate my risk function. I already calculated all $l(\theta, \theta^* ) $ for all possible values

Comment: Ah, you're worried about the P(x1,x2) term on the bottom of Bayes' formula?

Comment: By the way, do I need to use the posterior distribution to calculate $ \mathbb{E}[l(\theta, \theta^* ) ] ? Or I just consider this when I have some information (like a pair (x1,x2))? I don't see how to use the information of the probability of each pair and but I can't ignore it too.

Comment: Yes, Oscar. This is the point! If I had a formula for my posterior, I could calculate the expectation by hand without use that the bayes estimator is the mean of posterior distribution and just find my $ \theta^* = argmin(r(\theta)) = argmin ( \mathbb{E}[l(\theta, d] )$

Comment: @hejseb as i said, in this case we must consider the replacement. But it doesn't what is the problem is asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your prior. Since you have no information about the value of $\theta$ except that it's an integer between $0$ and $5$ a uniform prior is appropriate $P(\theta=0)=\dots=P(\theta=5)=1/6$

Then calculate your likelihoods $P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2|\theta=n)$ (which I'll abbreviate to $P(x_1,x_2|n)$).

Finally to use Bayes' rule you need $P(x_1,x_2)$ to go on the denominator. You can calculate this from the things you already have by using:
$$P(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{n=0}^5 P(x_1,x_2|n).P(\theta=n)$$
(This is called the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability))

Then you can calculate your posterior with Bayes:
$$P(\theta=n|x_1,x_2)=\frac{P(x_1,x_2|n).P(\theta=n)}{P(x_1,x_2)}$$
and from there you can minimise your expected loss (it's a property of the squared loss function that it's minimised by the mean of the posterior).

Comment: ok, I already did it. But, how can I find the mean of $ \theta | x_1,x_2 $ ? I mean, there is no drawn for I give a concrete formula for my posterior distribution to calculate by hand the mean. What should I do? Consider all the pairs (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,0)? In the bottom of the bayes equation, we will need to use both, but I dont get what will be $ P(x_1, x_2 | n) $ if I don,t even have x_1, x_2

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is confuse, but my problem is we don't have a pair (x_1, x_2) fixed (the probability of each different pair have a different equation in function of theta) to help me in this case

Comment: Yeah, do the problem four times, for each of the pairs $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1). You only really need to do it three times since (0,1) will give the same answer as (1,0).

Comment: Or you could try to write $P(x_1,x_2|\theta) as a function of $x_1+x_2$ and $\theta$ so you only have to do the calculation once. This would be the "hypergeometric distribution".

Comment: ok, the last one looks like a better idea. But, could we use the fact that $ f(\theta | (x1,x2) ) \propto L_X(\theta)f(\theta) $, where $L_X(\theta)$ is the likelihood function? So we will have: $f(\theta|x_1, x_2) \propto (5-\theta)^3 \theta^3 (4-\theta) $ Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe we can, using that the posterior is proportional to the likelihood function, calculate, by hand, the mean for each value of theta. I think that, if the function is correct, this holds

Comment: You're right that we can use the fact that $f(\theta|x_1,x_2)\propto L_X(\theta)$ but I think you're still confused. The likelihood function (and hence the posterior) should depend on the observed values $x_1$ and $x_2$. So we say $f(\theta|x_1,x_2)\propto (5-\theta)(4-\theta)$ if $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ and $f(\theta|x_1,x_2)\propto (5-\theta)\theta$ if $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ and $f(\theta|x_1,x_2)\propto \theta(\theta-1)$ if $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. So we get four different posteriors depending on the four different values for $(x_1,x_2)$. So the Bayes estimator for $\theta$ depends on the data.

Comment: Yes, I am confused about this part. But the way that this problem was construct is not helping. I mean, I need to find the best value of theta but I need to test for all possible ordered pair. If the urn contain 20 balls, it is not a convenient way to find the bayes estimator.

Comment: And yes, you were right about to consider all the cases. But we still don't have a good way to calculate the mean of each posterior obtained (but indeed, we can do this by hand). By the way, thanks for helping me